# Is it a bad idea to shower with the bathroom door open?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I live in an apartment alone and wonder if there are any dangers of taking hotish showers with the bathroom door open? I know that humidity is an enemy of electronics, but I am not sure if showering can even create enough humidity (unless maybe I put the electronics in the bathroom).

Before I used to shower with the door closed and then let the fan run after showering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No:  you are highly unlikely to have enough water vapor make its way through your door to any critical electronics placed elsewhere in the house.

Showering is also the enemy of sheetrock.  You're probably helping your walls by leaving the door open.  Or let the fan run while showering instead of just afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I am not quite sure what you mean by "water vapor make its way through your door to any critical electronics placed elsewhere in the house" if I have the door open.

Comment: I mean, as opposed to you having your computer in your shower room...

Answer (score 1):

I keep the bathroom door shut and the fan on while showering. I don't want water vapor to migrate back through the bathroom HVAC vent. On leaving I leave the fan on and shut the bathroom door, but come back a short while later, turn off fan and leave door open. My bathroom has not deteriorated in 38 years of my use, during which time it was renovated once.

Answer (score 1):

During the winter, I "want" to humidify the rest of the house. I haven't quite gotten to the point of leaving the door open (I'm worried that it would get drafty)  but I don't run the vent fan until the moisture is no longer helpful.